# Office 365 Integration / authentication - Server to Server calls

Tags: c#, api, office365, integration, office365api

Microsoft graph provides several nice examples of calling Office365 Group/Teams to fetch filenames, file metadata or any other data.
For example: 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample

All authentication examples I see is only where webbapplications redirects user to office 365 login dialogue and then redirect with bearer token.

Is there any way of implementing a server-to-server integration and execute the graph api calls? I.e one could build a scheduled server job which fetches information from office 365, for example file metadata for similar.